# im trying to get the index of words in a textbox.Text and add it to textBox2 but its not working good

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code :

```
private void BtnScrambleText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Enabled = false;
            BtnScrambleText.Enabled = false;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            var words = textBox1.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ', '"', ',', '-', '>', '\r', '\n', ':', '.', '<', '/', '=', '\\' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            int index = 0;
            int nextIndex = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            {
                string word = words[i];
                int wordWidth = word.Length;
                index = textBox1.Text.IndexOf(word, index);
                string t = textBox1.Text.Substring(nextIndex, index);
                textBox2.AppendText(t);
                string s = textBox1.Text.Substring(index, wordWidth);
                if (index == -1) break;

                if (word.Length > 0)
                {
                    ScrambleTextBoxText scrmbltb = new ScrambleTextBoxText(s.Trim());
                    scrmbltb.GetText();
                    sb.Append(word.Replace(s.Trim(), scrmbltb.scrambledWord));
                    textBox2.AppendText(sb.ToString());
                }

            }
        }
```

I know there are other ways but i want to use indexof and substring.

First im getting all the words from the textBox and add them to variable words.
Then in the loop first im getting the content of textBox1 untill the first word and add it to textBox2.

Then i find the first word index then substring so the variable s contain the word .
Im scrambling the word then add the word to textBox2.
The idea was :

1. To add the content untill the first word .
2. To add the scrambled word right after the first content.
3. To add the next content from the last found word untill the next word.
4. Add in the last position last index the next scrambled word.

And so on so in the end the content in textBox2 wil be the same format as it is in textBox1 but the words in textBox2 will be scrambled.

The problem is when i click the button its adding a lot of times the content and words to textBox2 and make a lot of mess.

Why is that how can i fix it ?

EDIT**

When entering manual text to the textBox1 for example:

```
    ? where am i ? ! hello im here -----
     _______________
```

what is the time in few hi everyone ? : >

I started to type in textBox1 after few spaces then added some chars like - ? > and more then i pressed the enter key and added the other line.

The result in textBox2 is:

wrhee     hlelo  hree -----
         ***_*__*_*___**

waht   tmie    evoyrnee

The words that i needed are scrambled good and in place the problem is that it didnt copy the signs ? and > and it didnt copy the rest of the content which wasnt scrambled. the words : is the few im hi wasnt copy to textBox2.

I wanted that the whole content to copy to textBox2 with spaces and everything but only the words i need to be scrambled.

The scramble part is working but the content copy is not.

Comment: This question is unclear to me. Could you provide some example of input (in `textBox1`) and output (in `textBox2`)?

Comment: King Kong i just did now. Also gave a link to my text file at the bottom here. The idea is to te copy the content of textBox1 to textBox2 like if i did : textBox2 = textBox1 but i need to do some manipulation of the words in textBox1 in the middle before i copy them to textBox2. So in the end it will be the same as in textBox1 like i did textBox2 = textBox1 but the only changes will be the words that are scrambled nothing else is change . Copy content from textBox1 to textBox2 untill the first word scramble the word add it to textBox2 in the right position and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines are the culprit:

```
string t = textBox1.Text.Substring(nextIndex, index);
textBox2.AppendText(t);
```

You are never setting `nextIndex` to anything. So essentially it is a constant zero that you set it at the beginning. `Substring(0,index)` means that each time you are adding the **entire content** from zero to the word that you have found. It reads from `nextIndex` for a **length** of `index`, not to position `index`.

Try replacing these two lines with something like this:

```
string t = textBox1.Text.Substring(nextIndex,index-nextIndex);//index-nextIndex is the length
nextIndex = index;
textBox2.AppendText(t);
```

**EDIT:** So I actually did some testing, and came up with this answer:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
var words = textBox1.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ', '"', ',',etc. },
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int index = 0;
int prevIndex = 0;
int prevWordWidth = 0;//This variable is now kept across iterations
for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    string word = words[i];

    //The non-scrambled string is from end of last word (prevIndex+prevWordWidth) 
    //up to the next word (index)
    index = textBox1.Text.IndexOf(word, prevIndex+prevWordWidth);
    string t = textBox1.Text.Substring(prevIndex+prevWordWidth, index-(prevIndex+prevWordWidth));

    prevIndex = index;
    prevWordWidth = word.Length;

    sb.Append(t);
    string s = textBox1.Text.Substring(index, prevWordWidth);
    if (index == -1) break;

    if (word.Length > 0)
    {
        ScrambleTextBoxText scrmbltb = new ScrambleTextBoxText(s.Trim());
        scrmbltb.GetText();
        sb.Append(word.Replace(s.Trim(), scrmbltb.scrambledWord));             
    }

}
textBox2.Text = sb.ToString(); //Note how this is only set at the end.
```

Those lines I mentioned above are still the main culprits, but also in every iteration of the loop you were appending the string builder to the Text Box. The point of the string builder (at least I thought so) is to build the string over the iterations and then add it all at once to the Text Box. So you only want to set `textBox2.Text` at the very end.

Comment: Omada no it didnt work it keep loading too much text to textBox2 and messy. I tried to type manualy in textBox1 the words : hi daniel hello hi and i got in textBox2 : hi dinealdaniel dinealhlleohello dinealhlleo      the words are scrambled as i wanted but there is no spaces between them and the words appear in textBox2 twice or more !

Comment: The important thing is to add the text back to textBox2 with the same spaces between words just the same format as it was in textBox1

Comment: I tried it manualy for the testing my question is when i tried to load a text file from my hard disk which contain a much more text then 4 words there are about 326 words but it dosent matter it dosent work good so far .

Comment: This is what I get for posting code without testing it! Give me a bit, I am working on it.

Comment: Omada just in the begining im getting and exception on the line : string t = textBox1.Text.Substring(prevIndex + prevWordWidth, index - (prevIndex + prevWordWidth)); Length cannot be less than zero when im using adding a text file to the textBox1. index = 72 prevIndex = 72 and prevWordWidth = 7 and i = 7 so it was in the itertion 7 . The word was "Android"

Comment: Omada if you want to try it with my text file here is a link to download it : https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=EB1C71C44C3976D5!273&authkey=!AFLpHZmSqEdsya0 the file is only 2.21KB contain some hebrew fonts/letters inside but the problem is with the code not the hebrew

Comment: Omada the code is working if i type words manualy in the textBox1 the problem is when i tried to load/open/add the content text from the text file.

Comment: Odama no its not working good even when doing it manualy i just updated my question !

Comment: @Haim Kashi Updated the code, the line that had `index = textBox1.Text.IndexOf`, that exception should be gone now.